# Smtp Authentication

Tags: java, smtp, email

I am writing a class to connect to a SMTP server over SSL and send a mail. The smtp server i am using (yahoo) requires authentication. Can someone tell me how the authentication takes place as to which commands i should use to send my user credentials?

Note: I know about the JavaMail API. I just want a simple class to send mail without outside libraries.

Comment: Reinventing the wheel is rarely a good idea. Unless there is a very compelling reason not to use an existing library it would be foolish to re-implement it, even if you are only interested in a part of it.

Answer (score 3):

[Internet RFC 821](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc821.html) covers the basics of the SMTP protocol, and [RFC 2554](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2554.html) covers the authentication extensions.  You'll need many of them to get a functional SMTP client up.

But, really, it's much simpler to just use JavaMail (unless this is a homework assignment, in which case, I'm guessing that would be cheating.)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by following in c#

```
class smtp
{
    SmtpClient client;
    MailMessage   mm;

    void send()
    {
      mm.send();
    }


    void smtp_configure()
    {
     client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
                client.Port = smtp_port;
                client.Host = smtp_host;              
                client.EnableSsl = true;
    }
    message_configure()
    {
      mm = new MailMessage(From, To);
      mm.Body = MgsText;
      mm.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
      mm.Subject = Subject;
    }

   Main()
   {
      smtp_configure();
      message_configure();
      send();
    }

}
```

Comment: TODO:  figure out the right ```import``` statements to get this working.

[javax-mail][]

[javax.mail]: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/javamail145-1904579.html